# Input a command from a Sensor to get data through an IP Address in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sensors

I have an instrument called Picarro G2401 where I need to see data from it. In order to see the data the Instrument have its own command which is (_Meas_GetConc). When I do it in putty and input the command it shows the data. See the image below.

[image: Putty]

I don't know where to put this command in order to make it work.

Below find the an image where it says that it is connected but no data is given.

[image: Tester]

MainForm.cs

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private PicarroG2401 sensor = new PicarroG2401(new IPAddress(new byte[] {10, 71, 3, 4}));

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.sensor.Connected += Sensor_Connected;
        this.sensor.Disconnected += Sensor_Disconnected;
        this.sensor.DataReceived += Sensor_DataReceived;
        this.sensor.Startup();
    }

    private void Sensor_DataReceived(object sender, DataReading reading)
    {
        this.data.AppendText(reading.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void Sensor_Disconnected(object sender, TCPSensor sensor)
    {
        this.data.AppendText("Disconnected" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void Sensor_Connected(object sender, TCPSensor sensor)
    {
        this.data.AppendText("Connected" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.sensor.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

PicarroG2401 - Class

```
namespace SensorDriverLibrary.Instruments
{
    [Serializable]
    public class PicarroG2401 : TCPSensor
    {
        public PicarroG2401(IPAddress ip) : base(ip, 51020)
        {
        }

        public override SensorTypes GetSensorType()
        {
            return SensorTypes.PicarroG2401;
        }

        protected override DataReading processData()
        {
            base.processData();
            if (this.tcpClient != null && this.tcpClient.Connected && this.tcpClient.Available > 0)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(this.tcpClient.GetStream());
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                PicarroG2401_DataReading reading = new PicarroG2401_DataReading(line);
                this.lastRead = DateTime.Now;
                this.OnDataReceived(reading);
                return reading;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

PicarroG2401_DataReading

```
namespace SensorDriverLibrary.Instruments
{
    [Serializable]
    public class PicarroG2401_DataReading : DataReading
    {
        public PicarroG2401_DataReading() : base()
        { }

        public PicarroG2401_DataReading(string data) : base()
        {   
            //409.541;1.940;0.123;1.301
            //012345678901234567890123456789
            //0         1         2
            //CO2      CH4   CO     H2O  
            data = data.Substring(29);
            string[] elements = data.Replace("\n\r", "").Split(';');
            this.CO2 = float.Parse(elements[0]);
            this.CH4 = float.Parse(elements[1]);
            this.CO = float.Parse(elements[2]);
            this.H2O = float.Parse(elements[3]);
        }

        public override void ReadFromFile(FileStream file)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
            file.Read(bytes, 0, 8);
            this.Timestamp = new DateTime(BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0));
            file.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
            this.co2 = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
            file.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
            this.ch4 = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
            file.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
            this.co = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
            file.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
            this.h2o = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
        }

        public override void WriteToFile(FileStream file)
        {
            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(this.Timestamp.Ticks);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(this.co2);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(this.ch4);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(this.co);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(this.h2o);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() +
                this.CO2.ToString("0.000") + " " +
                this.CH4.ToString("0.000") + " " +
                this.CO.ToString("0.000") + " " +
                this.H2O.ToString("0.000");
        }

        public override string GetHTMLTable()
        {
            string table = "<table>";
            table += "<tr><td>CO2</td><td>" + this.CO2.ToString("0.000") + " ppm" + "</td></tr>";
            table += "<tr><td>CH4</td><td>" + this.CH4.ToString("0.000") + " ppm" + "</td></tr>";
            table += "<tr><td>CO</td><td>" + this.CO.ToString("0.000") + " ppm" + "</td></tr>";
            table += "<tr><td>H2O</td><td>" + this.H2O.ToString("0.000") + " %" + "</td></tr>";
            table += "</table>";
            return table;
        }

        private float co2 = 0;  //ppm
        public float CO2
        {
            get
            {
                return this.co2;
            }
            set
            {
                this.co2 = value;
            }
        }

        private float ch4 = 0;  //ppm
        public float CH4
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ch4;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ch4 = value;
            }
        }

        private float co = 0;   //ppm
        public float CO
        {
            get
            {
                return this.co;
            }
            set
            {
                this.co = value;
            }
        }

        private float h2o = 0;  // %
        public float H2O
        {
            get
            {
                return this.h2o;
            }
            set
            {
                this.h2o = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your PicarroG2401  only reads, shouldn't there be a method to send data to the sensor?

Comment: How are you using PuTTY to connect to the sensor (SSH/Telnet/SCP/Serial Port/Raw Socket)?

Comment: I am choosing Raw, then I input the IP and port and press ok. The I input the command and press enter.

Comment: where and when, in your code, do you send the command _Meas_GetConc to the sensor?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a background with Java? In C# you don't need, and typically will not explicitly reference `this` for class variables, but as a convention instead private class variables will have a leading _ before the variable name and the `this` is removed.

Comment: Also, for all of your public properties like `public float CO2` you don't need to explicitly define your getters and setters like you have. All of them can be shortened to `public float CO2 { get; set; }` which implicitly defines your getter and setter and allows you to remove the private backing fields

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to same device?  You c# code is returning "Connected" and cannot figure out where that is coming from.  Putty doesn't have "Connected".  To me it looks like you are connected to a different device.  Are you running from same machine with putty and c#?  You may have two machine with same IP.  To make sure you are connecting to correct device from cmd.exe >Ping IP.  Then remove ethernet cable from sensor.  Then do ping again and see if you get a response.  If you get a response than you are connected to wrong machine.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't have enough info to verify this answer, but this is too much for a oomment.

In PicarroG2401.processData(), you'll need to send the command string to the sensor before attempting to read the result. Something like this:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(this.tcpClient.GetStream());
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(this.tcpClient.GetStream()); 
writer.WriteLine("_Meas_GetConc");
writer.Flush();
string line = reader.ReadLine();
```

I think you will want to remove the condition `this.tcpClient.Available > 0`, as the sensor will not have sent any data until it receives the command.

Now, this assumes that the line ending chosen by StreamWriter and StreamReader match the line ending required/sent by the sensor. If it doesn't, you may have additional work to do.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it work the code below was the issue -

```
    protected override DataReading processData()
    {
        base.processData();
        if (this.tcpClient != null && this.tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());
            writer.WriteLine("_Meas_GetConc\n\r");
            writer.Flush();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream()); 
            string line = reader.ReadLine();               
            PicarroG2401_DataReading reading = new PicarroG2401_DataReading(line);
            lastRead = DateTime.Now;
            OnDataReceived(reading);
            return reading;
        }
        return null;
    }
```